# How to ignore transparent pixels of an image?

Tags: css, hover, transparency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hit detection on non-transparent pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878511/hit-detection-on-non-transparent-pixel)

`#welc` is a transparent .png. Non-transparent pixels are placed diagonally, like a ribbon, so the majority of the image (top-left and bottom-right parts) are - transparent.

```
#welc:hover{
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

This works, but I want this effect only if mouse is over the "real image", i.e. over non-transparent pixels.

Comment: Note that changing an element position when it's hovered is a bad idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak, could you explain, pls.

Comment: Not possible through straight css and the alternatives are not trivial. Possible way using [hit detection on transparent pixel using canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878511/hit-detection-on-non-transparent-pixel)

Comment: If you move an element when it's hovered, the move could cause the element to not be hovered, which will move the element back, which will cause it to become hovered...

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes, i noticed this. Is there any way to prevent div's come back, once when it is hovered ?

Comment: In short, a dumb browser (I distinctly remember this happening) will keep toggling the states 'till the end of time (or until you move the mouse). A smart browser (I think this is the case nowadays) will keep the element rendered as hovered even if it's not - until you move the mouse.

Comment: The typical solution is to _expand_ an element. One way is to move an element but keep the hover pseudoclass on its parent which doesn't move.

Comment: @JanDvorak, i think I'll remove this effect. Too many jobs for a small thing. Thanks a lot, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could mask the opaque areas with an image map and only apply the hover when the cursor is over the mask. I don't know if that's a cross-browser safe solution.

Comment: AFAIR, image maps themselves have existed since the dawn of time. I also assume the masks can be `hover`ed.

Comment: This would require quite a lot of image processing to get at the pixel values if it is not static and one hell of an image map (pixel level mapping...)

Comment: @PaulSullivan hopefully the image is static and the image map can be produced manually. From the description, it seems to be the case.

Comment: Agreed @JanDvorak - manual and painful but it should work (just hope its not a big image and that the OP is allowing fuzzy edge detection not pixel perfect) :s

Comment: Thanks to everyOne. I'll see - what to do.

Comment: Thinking about it @JanDvorak this is probably the easiest route, most crossbrowser compliant (canvas and js support needed for other) and less cpu intensive